# Tree based time series forecasts, inference on slopes?

Tags: time-series, boosting

I've heard that ensemble methods have been used to mixed effect on time series models. Their biggest issue is that they cannot predict something they haven't seen before, so they struggle trends, whereas they're a bit better equipped for seasonality.

My question is, is there any research in predicting the slope between adjacent points?

For example, $X = [5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9]$ has $N$ elements. But slopes $S$ would have $N-1$ elements account for each adjacent pair. $[\frac{7-5}{t}, \frac{6-7}{t}, ...]$ where $t$ is the interval between observations (presumably 1.)

If an ensemble method, for example XGBoost, was supposed to not predict $P(X_t|X_{t-1...t-n})$ but the slopes, $P(S_{(t,t-1)}|S_{(t-1, t-2), (t-2, t-3) ...})$, then the issue of what the model has or hasn't seen before would theoretically mitigated. It would require $X_t$ and $t$ to determine how to augment the most recent $X_{t-1}$ by the predicted slope.

The biggest drawback is that the loss function will be evaluated in terms of predicted slopes, not the actual prediction of $X_t$.

I'm curious if this has been asked or researched before?

Comment: Are you just fitting this to the first difference then? I assume that the slopes can be seen as the "stationary version" of the sample at hand. I haven't seen any papers about that, it can often be assumed as part of the preprocessing.

Comment: Yup exactly, I’ll give it a go. Low cost to try